# GTK theme inspector for Desktop Enviroment elements

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, gtk, pantheon, design

Ever used *firebug* or *google chrome inspector*? Is there any similar way to inspect elements in the desktop environment to get their "element name" or "class" or "id"?

Actually I've installed the os x Yosemite theme on my Elementary OS but there are a few of the elements in the DE which does not seem to look good e.g. the menus on the wingpanel and slingsot items. I opened up the theme files and there is CSS styling. I can write CSS but how will I know which *class* or *element* to use as a selector? Although there are comments in the **apps.css** and **gtk-widgets.css** files which indicate the css for a few elements like slingshot but when i make change to them nothing happens.

Is there any tool available out there which can help me do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Gtk Inspector**. To enable it open a terminal and execute :

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

And now you can launch it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Source: [Gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector)

Comment: When I try the above it says "No such schema 'org.gtk.Settings.Debug'". Am I missing any package?

Comment: Okay so after doing "sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev" the error message is gone. 
But it looks like this debugger only inspects a few GTK apps but what I am trying to achieve is to debug desktop environment things like the slingshot. Anything for this?

Comment: If someone is unable to launch the debugger in DE elements, see @Defman 's answer!

Answer (score 1):

To debug the DE itself (I assume you want to debug a wingpanel widget), you need to somehow focus them. The easiest way I use is opening Slingshot (or any other wingpanel indicator), hovering your mouse over it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>. The best position to hover your mouse over to inspect the slingshot widget is this little triangle (don't know the proper name for it):

[image: Imgur]

Of course <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> will work only if gtk debugging is enabled.